# Magento 1.7 Why are my sessions getting mixed up?

Tags: php, session, cookies, magento-1.7, magento-fpc

I've created two customer login accounts. I log in with customer 1 then customer2. When i'm clicking around in customers 1 account customers 2 data is displayed.

I have `<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>` in my `app/etc/local.xml`

I'm using Chrome to test and i'm `Right Click->Inspect->Application->Cookies` and i'm seeing the adminhtml value change when the bug occurs.

[image]

Why are my sessions messed up and loading other customers information?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually not a session problem. Mostly it is caused by misconfiguration of Full Page cache.

Try to disable and clear all caches
Purge all files in /var/session
and try again